# Automatic measurements of polygon sides not working in QGIS

Tags: gis, qgis

I want to use a style to convert a kml layer to have measurements on all size, kind of like:

[image]

I'm using  QGIS 3.28 LTE. I started by downloading the style from https://plugins.qgis.org/styles/21/ which is a zip file. I extracted the contained xml file and uploaded it using the setting -> style manager option

If I look in the style manager I now have:

[image]

I've installed the KML tools plugin and used this to create a polygon layer from the kml layer . Next I double clicked on the output polygon label , and added the " Measure feet " Label.

However when I look at the polygon layer, I see:

[image]

The KML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="2963760840" id="2963760840">
    <SimpleField name="timestamp" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="begin" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="end" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="altitudeMode" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="tessellate" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="extrude" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="visibility" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="drawOrder" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="icon" type="string"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder><name>2963760840</name>
<Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#2963760840">
        <SimpleData name="tessellate">-1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="extrude">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="visibility">-1</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
    <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-88.4317405175818,31.6558800962605 -88.431737410907,31.6559161822374 -88.4317340478576,31.6559522520483 -88.4317304294607,31.65598830298 -88.4317265546618,31.6560243350402 -88.4317224234424,31.6560603464253 -88.4317180368385,31.656096335324 -88.4317133937868,31.6561323008421 -88.4317084963772,31.6561682411606 -88.4317033435555,31.6562041562871 -88.4316979352941,31.6562400435163 -88.4316922726381,31.6562759019385 -88.4316863545151,31.6563117297579 -88.4316801819788,31.6563475269666 -88.4316737560565,31.6563832908516 -88.4316670756934,31.6564190214205 -88.4316601419166,31.6564547159601 -88.4316529536625,31.6564903735763 -88.4316455130305,31.6565259933519 -88.431637818957,31.6565615743927 -88.4316298724689,31.6565971139855 -88.431621673566,31.6566326121303 -88.4316132232843,31.6566680670158 -88.4316045205513,31.6567034768459 -88.4315955664119,31.6567388407112 -88.431586360857,31.6567741577097 -88.4315817286416,31.6567915607419 -88.4311466897599,31.6584809674529 -88.4311356263598,31.658529215528 -88.431124815372,31.6585775059521 -88.431114256788,31.6586258378234 -88.4311039516355,31.658674208429 -88.4310938999238,31.6587226186706 -88.4310841005811,31.6587710667524 -88.431074554662,31.6588195526667 -88.4310652631943,31.6588680737005 -88.4310562240697,31.6589166298692 -88.4310474404426,31.6589652202479 -88.4310389101867,31.6590138430485 -88.4310306343658,31.6590624991651 -88.4310226129532,31.6591111858924 -88.4310148459404,31.6591599023285 -88.4310073343821,31.6592086484659 -88.4310000772153,31.6592574234104 -88.4309930754678,31.6593062244489 -88.430986329149,31.6593550524834 -88.4309798382413,31.6594039057101 -88.4309736027451,31.6594527841292 -88.4309720419662,31.6594653415 -88.4309644366008,31.6595394733955 -88.4309570876343,31.6596136241626 -88.4309499950584,31.6596877928994 -88.4309431588736,31.659761979606 -88.4309365790716,31.6598361833805 -88.4309302545895,31.6599104033289 -88.4309241875368,31.6599846394358 -88.4309183768417,31.6600588899053 -88.4309128225048,31.6601331547375 -88.4309075245268,31.6602074339324 -88.4309024839445,31.6602817256786 -88.4308976996953,31.6603560290821 -88.4308931717888,31.6604303450447 -88.4308889012709,31.660504672657 -88.43088488707,31.6605790101229 -88.4308831265363,31.6606132013205 -88.430880160709,31.6606753008115 -88.4308774511835,31.6607374083529 -88.4308749990237,31.6607995248388 -88.4308728042029,31.6608616475637 -88.4308708656675,31.6609237765354 -88.4308691844632,31.6609859108443 -88.4308677605907,31.6610480504906 -88.4308665929691,31.6611101927763 -88.4308656826711,31.6611723394975 -88.4308650296705,31.6612344879487 -88.430864901764,31.6612506351474 -88.4326782034786,31.6612204116202 -88.432897502907,31.6542440681409 -88.4317454858576,31.6541186481987 -88.4317646239949,31.6548099837846 -88.431765521614,31.65484436124 -88.4317663085529,31.6548787413071 -88.4317669858568,31.6549131230762 -88.4317675535255,31.6549475065475 -88.4322256604991,31.6549477172071 -88.4321986103415,31.6558080866836 -88.4317459607727,31.6558078776201 -88.4317433668281,31.6558439941254 -88.4317405175818,31.6558800962605</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

I don't see any measurements. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your style's link: `The layer MUST be in a projected coordinate system with either "meters" or "feet" as unit of measurement`.
Your polygon's coords are in degrees. You should reproject:
Take a breath, it's not difficult: 1) start a new project. 2) go to menu `Project`, go down to `Properties` and click it. 3) in the window that will open, find the `CRS` entry at left side and click it. 4) on the right, you will see a list of available CRSs - pick a proper one (in the area of your kml and with meters as units) and you are set.
[image: see caption of project properties]

PS: Your recent questions diverge from your original post. I'm happy to keep helping if I can, but I think your original question has been answered and you should mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Thank you. How do you know its in degrees and how do you reproject?

Comment: coords like -80,31 are degrees, not meters and are typically used in projection systems like WGS84 (GPS, Google etc). For an easy way to reproject, try this: Start a new QGIS project, go to its properties and set its CRS to a planar value (it will be in meters) and then load your kml there. Which CRS you should choose, depends on the place (country) your kml falls in.  If my answer covers your question, please accept it. If you need additional info, let me know.

Comment: I'm pretty new to QGIS and mapping . Could you point me to a more detailed set of instructions - ie article, screenshots video, etc

Comment: Modified answer with instructions and screenshot. HTH

Comment: Thank you - A follow up if I may: My property is in eastern alabama and I couldn't find an obvious match for the location and with feet (I prefer that over metres). Is there a web site to look up an appropriate crs? Also How far away can the CRS be - i.e. lets say I found one in Western Alabama with feet, could I use that?

Comment: No problem, as many as you need. When you click on a CRS, its area, i.e. the area over which it produces valid transformations, is shown in the window (see the red rectangle in my screenshot). Furthermore, you can search in the same window: I searched for 'alabama' (at the top, where it says 'Filter') and, going over each of the 9 results, I think what you need is "NAD_1983_StatePlane_Alabama_East_FIPS_0101_Feet - ESRI:102629".

Comment: Thank you - that really helps. - I may post a follow up question later